# Creating a backup of a file with copy after_save, goes into endless loop

Tags: excel, vba, backup

I wrote a code to run when user saves workbook, this code saves another copy, and then saves the original file again, to avoid leaving user editing the "backup" workbook.

Once it saves the original file again, the "after_save" trigger is fired, and keeps saving to infinity.

I checked for a solution here on StackOverFlow but haven't found one.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Call SaveToLocations
End Sub

Sub SaveToLocations()
    Dim WoExt, Ext, BkPath, nDateTime As String
    Static OrigName As String

    'defining variables
    nDateTime = Format(Now, "YYMMDD")
    OrigName = "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\vbatest\test orig.xlsm"
    Ext = ".xls"
    WoExt = "test orig"
    BkPath = "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\vbatest\Backup\"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (BkPath + WoExt + " - Backup - " + nDateTime + Ext)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs OrigName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `SaveCopyAs` to avoid having to resave, and try using `If Workbook.Saved = True` to avoid getting into a saving loop

Comment: First of all if you want to keep archive it should run when the user opens the workbook not when changes are applied and user is trying to save it. Your so called original would be simply another copy of edited workbook.

Comment: As a part of your application logic, you should manage a variable `Public SaveCopy As Boolean` that will indicate whether to save or not

Comment: edit:That's a very good point @Masoud and it worked, you should post it as an answer so i can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an archive, you need to save the workbook when opening it, not at the end when the user is closing it. The code below takes care of this:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
 Dim WoExt, Ext, BkPath, nDateTime As String

 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    'defining variables
    nDateTime = Format(Now, "YYMMDD")
    Ext = ".xls"
    WoExt = ThisWorkbook.Name
    BkPath = "C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Desktop\vbatest\Backup\"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (BkPath + WoExt + " - Backup - " + nDateTime + Ext)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
             MsgBox "Backup has not been saved."
End Sub
```

This just saves the backup and leaves saving the edits to the user at the end.

Comment: I would keep the extension in the name (last .xls will be the extension) for the sake of keeping the record that what was the actual extension of the file.